# Jenkins Pipeline UCDeploy Multiple 'deployVersions'

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, ucd

I'm attempting to setup a Jenkins pipeline that will deploy multiple components of an application in a single step. I was able to do this successfully with multiple deploy steps, but I would like to have it all in the same step to avoid multiple server restarts. According to IBM:

> Versions to deploy. Specify multiple on a new line in the format
> component:version

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Deploy to TEST') {
            steps {
                step([$class: 'UCDeployPublisher',
                    siteName: 'mySite',
                    deploy: [
                        $class: 'com.urbancode.jenkins.plugins.ucdeploy.DeployHelper$DeployBlock',
                        deployApp: 'myApp',
                        deployEnv: 'TEST',
                        deployVersions: 'appComponent1:${appCom1Version}',
                        deployVersions: 'appComponent2:${appCom2Version}',
                        deployVersions: 'appComponent3:${appCom3Version}',
                        deployProc: 'Deploy',
                        deployOnlyChanged: false
                    ]
                ])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running this, it seems like it's falling through and only deploying the last component:version.

Comment: According to the source code, `deployVersions` is a String type, and therefore you can only specify one version per class constructor arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use delimiter `\n` to separate multiple components' version to install

```
deployVersions: "appComponent1:${appCom1Version}\nappComponent2:${appCom2Version}",
```